# React state array issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to store array objects in react state. I don't know what I'm missing but my code is not working. Here is my code below :

```
export default class Groups extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tabledata: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      tabledata: [...this.state.tabledata, {"name": "name1"}]
    })

    console.log("HI")
    console.log(this.state.tabledata)
  }
}
```

The console log return empty state not storing anyting in state array.. Please suggest what's wrong here. Thank you in advance..

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous.

Comment: can you please explain more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push the object(s) into the array:

```
    export default class Groups extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        tabledata: []
      }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({
        // tabledata: [...this.state.tabledata, {"name": "name1"}]
            tabledata: this.state.tabledata.push({"name": "name1"})
      })

      console.log("HI")
      console.log(this.state.tabledata)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate problems there, but both spring from the same cause: [State updates are asynchronous.](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

So the two problems are:

1. You're setting state based on existing state by passing an object into `setState`. That could set stale state. When updating state based on existing state, you **must** use the callback version of `setState`.
2. You're logging state immediately after calling `setState`. That won't see the updated state, because the update is asynchronous. Instead, log it in the completion callback (if you need to do something with it; normally, you don't need this, just allow React to re-render, which it will do by default).

Here are those corrections applied to your code:

```
export default class Groups extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tabledata: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(
      // Update callback receives the current state. Here I'm picking
      // `tabledata` from it via destructuring
      ({tabledata}) => ({
        tabledata: [...tabledata, {"name": "name1"}]
      }),
      // Completion callback
      () => {
        console.log("HI")
        console.log(this.state.tabledata)
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
class Groups extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tabledata: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(
      ({tabledata}) => ({
        tabledata: [...tabledata, {"name": "name1"}]
      }),
      () => {
        console.log("HI")
        console.log(this.state.tabledata)
      }
    )
  }
  
  render() {
    return this.state.tabledata.map(({name}) => <div>{name}</div>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Groups />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Again, though, normally you don't need or want to use the completion callback, so:

```
export default class Groups extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tabledata: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(({tabledata}) => ({
      tabledata: [...tabledata, {"name": "name1"}]
    }));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this option before, but it was returning empty. So now also it's returning empty again

Comment: @David - The above definitely works, see the live example. I did have a typo (`tableData` instead of `tabledata`), perhaps you also had a typo?

Comment: yes I observed the typo, I corrected it then also it is returning me blank. And thank you for live example. I'll go through my code once again..